# How do I solve this recursive equation which involves square root?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, summation, recurrence-relations, nested-radicals

Please suggest a way to solve the following recursive equation:
$$x=\sqrt{1+a^2_{n} e^2+2 a_{n} e f}$$ where $$a_{n}=\sqrt{1+a^2_{n-1} e^2+2 a_{n-1} e f},   a_{n-1}=\sqrt{1+a^2_{n-2} e^2+2 a_{n-2} e f}$$ and so on. Does this type of equations have a special name?

Comment: Note that the first equation is already solved in terms of $x$, so there needs to be some more clarity there on what is to be solved for.  The recurrence relation expressed in the second equation is potentially solvable, but note that this particular recurrence will very easily be insoluble and/or unbounded for certain sets of values $e,f$.  Please verify that you are interested in solubility vs. boundedness of solutions.

Comment: Did you mean to say $a_{n+1}$ instead of $x$?

Comment: Apologies my question was not correctly posed.  Yes, it is $a_{n+1}$ I am interested. $e$ and $f$ takes values between -1 and +1.

Answer (score 2):

Such non-linear recurrences very seldom have closed form solutions.

What are $e$, $f$? Ranges of interest? For instance, for $e = f = 1$ it reduces to $a_{n + 1} = \lvert a_n + 1 \rvert$. What is $a_0$ (your starting point)? Any further information, i.e., is $a_n$ expected to be large or small with respect to $1$?

In what are you interested? Is it enough to e.g. get a limit for $a_n$ as $n \to \infty$? Is an asymptotic bound enough?

Comment: $a_{n+1}<1$. e  and f take values between -1 and +1.  An asymptotic bound is enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to have $a_{n+1}$ instead of $x$, these kinds of equations may be solved only asymptotically. I replace constants to avoid confusion of what you meant by $e$.

$$a_{n+1}^2=1+a_{n}^2d^2+2a_{n}dc$$

Let us write

$$a_{n}=g_{n}e^n$$

This leads to

$$g_{n+1}^2=\frac1{e^{2(n+1)}}+\frac{g_{n}^2e^{2n}d^2}{e^{2(n+1)}}+\frac{2g_{n}e^{n}dc}{e^{2(n+1)}}$$

$$g_{n+1}^2 \sim \frac{g_{n}^2d^2}{e^2}=g_{n}^2h$$

or

$$g_{n+1} \sim g_{n}\sqrt{h}$$

which has an obvious solution $g_{n+1} \sim kc^n$

Obviously the asymptotic solution, the solution at infinity, is

$$a_{n} \sim k_1e^{k_2n}$$

where you need to adjust $k_1$ and $k_2$ based on the constants involved and initial conditions.

Typically what you do next once you have asymptotic solution is to express $a_n$ using multiplication or addition with another function trying to get closer to the expression for smaller values of $n$. This typically leads to obtaining a solution in form of series. If you achieve a convergent series and there is some generic way of expressing the expansion terms, technically, you have found a solution.